# Passing various ssh connections in linux command without duplicating code

Tags: bash, ssh

I have shell script which connects to various linux machines but every machine's SSH connection way is different and mostly falls for two category
1. Public/private key
2. sshpass.

Shell script having ~100 such commands so i can't put if else condition everywhere, instead of that i tried to put command at top which will give me sshConnection and which would be used in all command but it doesn't work.

```
if [ "${service}" = "Node-Machine" ]; then
    sshConnection="ssh ${awsUser}@${fullMachineName} "
else
    sshConnection="sshpass -p ${machinePassword} ssh root@${fullMachineName} "
fi

# Use of command
tempDir=`${sshConnection} "su - www-data -c \"ls -l\""`

/sshConnection.sh: line 35: ssh ubuntu@ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com : command not found
```

How can we pass such ssh connections in linux command without duplicating code?

Comment: Your code looks good to me ; your error suggests that you have extra quotes that make `bash` parse `ssh ubuntu@ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com` as a single token, a command, rather than two tokens, a command and its parameter.

Comment: Hmm I'm bothered that I can't point out the extra quotes from your code ; also the question should probably be closed as "typographical error" (not a critic of your question, but because it likely won't be found by someone having the same problem)

Comment: Sorry variable value is not passed correctly if i use single quote and still gives issue for command not found.

Comment: Both single-quotes and double-quotes will group words in a single token (the difference is whether expansion will be done). You should group them when affecting the command&params to a variable, but you should avoid them when referencing that variable : `var="command param"` then `result=$($var extraparams)` rather than `result=$("$var" extraparams)` ; but that's already what you've done in the code you posted above...

Comment: I'm sorry but that is the question and it doesn't work for me, i pass values directly then only works but i want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: No need to be sorry ! However, I think the problem's cause isn't represented in the code extract you posted. Here's a somewhat similar code that show what works and what doesn't and how it produces the error you see : [ideone](https://ideone.com/XhC8ud). You might want to make sure the `sshConnection` var isn't modified further, and maybe use `bash -x`/`set -x` to debug the problem (it would likely show `'ssh ubuntu@ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com' 'su - www-data -c "ls -l"'` just before the error is raised, and might help you find out where the extra quotes come from)